# ARIMA miscalculates the result and I get the error: Warning:Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters found.Using zeros as starting parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I need to calculate [ARIMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html) on several values in a loop. All results are obtained successfully, except the one that has values `x = [0, 2]`. Maybe there are two values are too few, but it's part of a loop where the number of values is various, so I can't predict where there are only two values (assuming the problem is that there are two values)

The calculated result is `-9.995715227417712e-06`, and i get this error:

```
    warn('Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters'
UserWarning: Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters found. Using zeros as starting parameters.

    warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "
ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
```

I tried to insert any third number into `x` ([0, 2, 0] or [0, 2, 2], or [0, 2, 3], etc...) and i don't see the error (except for 1, for example x = [0, 2, 1] , which still makes me see the error).

How can I use `x = [0, 2]` (just 0 and 2) and correctly calculate the result without seeing the error?

Here's how I'm using ARIMA:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

x = [0, 2]
model = ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit()
forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=1)

print(forecast[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'm not 100% sure why it works.

By default `trend` is set to 'c', which is constant trend (basically a linear intercept.) If you set it to 'n' or 'ct', the error goes away.

If you set it to 'n', it predict a near-zero value.

If you set it to 'ct', it basically becomes a linear regression, and predicts a point by drawing a straight line through your two points and predicting 4.

Code example:

```
model = ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0), trend='ct')
```

I also got convergence errors when using 'ct' on more than 2 values if those values were in an exactly straight line.

I think this has something to do with the fact that the default settings have three unknowns and two observations, and that would explain why 'n' works, because removing trends reduces it to two parameters. But it doesn't explain why 'ct' works, because that has *four* parameters.

Comment: Can you show me how and where I should write trends?

Comment: @Joseph_123 I added an example. See edit.

Comment: I'm looking for a different result. For example if I use x = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2], its simple arithmetic mean is 1.6. With model = ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0)), I get 1.38. So I look for a result that is slightly lower than the simple average, as in the case of 1.6 becoming 1.38. If I use x = [0, 2], the simple average is 2. So I expected to receive a result less than 2. With trend='ct' I receive 3.39, while with trend='n' I receive 9.45-06. Is there anything that would cause me to receive a value below the simple average?

Comment: @Joseph_123 Wouldn't the average of [0, 2] be 1? Can you clarify what you mean by simple average?

Comment: Yes, 1. Sorry, careless error. Considering that the average of [0,2] is 1, then I would like to get a result that is less than 1 (for example 0.65, or 0.70, or 0.75, or 0.80, or something like that). It's the same thing that happened with simple model = ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0)), when for example I used x = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2] and received 1.38 as a result (average was 1.6) I would like to do the same for x= [0, 2] (or something similar anyway)

Comment: You could do `if len(x) < 3: forecast = np.mean(x) * 0.80`

Comment: Are you saying that: if there are less than 3 values in x, then forecast is equal to mean * 0.80? Why * 0.80?

Comment: @Joseph_123 1.38 / 1.6 = 0.86, you suggested that 1 should become something between 0.65-0.80. So I picked the extreme end of that range.

Comment: I said this just to give you an example of what i needed with ARIMA. Writing np.mean(x) * 0.80 is a gamble, it is a very IMPRECISE result. I said it just to give you an example that the result of ARIMA must be less than the simple arithmetic mean.This answer goes off topic, because i need a result with ARIMA.I'm not very experienced with ARIMA,this is the first time I've used it.You are certainly more talented and experienced than me:do you have any ideas on how I can avoid that mistake with ARIMA and get a below average result like I did with simple model=ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0)),?

Comment: (continuation of the comment above). Your answer, makes the error disappear, true, but with it I get a result that is completely different from what I was looking for with model=ARIMA(x, order=(1,0,0)). I'm surprised that someone as talented and experienced as you can't find a solution to this simple question. So unfortunately your answer is not helpful to me. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: 1) I don't think there's a principled way to fit an ARIMA to two observations. Anything you pick will create a linear function of x[0] and x[1], with different coefficients. e.g. the answer given by the original code is x[0], linear regression is -x[0]+2*x[1], an order (0,0,0) model is 0.5*x[0]+0.5*x[1].  Every answer is in some sense arbitrary. This one is just a little more clear about its arbitrariness. 2) If you have a specific idea about what answer it should give, you should put that in the question.